# Fontawesome Icons are not showing with bootstrap classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, icons, font-awesome

I am trying to use [Fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io) icons with [boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com). I wan to show some of the icons at the end of jumbotron. But they are not showing up.

Here's the code I am using:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Muhammad Arslan Aslam</h1>
        <h4>Front-End Web Designer, and Junior Blogger. <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" herf="about.html">Know More</a></h4>
        Join Me:
        <a href="http://facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square-2x">&nbsp;</i></a>
    </div>
```

I have intergrated fontawesome using CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0qftoLp7/1/

Instead of `facebook-square-2x`, it's `facebook-square fa-2x`

**HTML**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Muhammad Arslan Aslam</h1>
        <h4>Front-End Web Designer, and Junior Blogger. <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" herf="about.html">Know More</a></h4>
        Join Me:
        <a href="http://facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you very much @adib-behjat it worked very fine for me :)